# How to handle authentication to MongoDB from Hibernate application

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, authentication

I need to catch errors during authentication (like wrong parameters). I find nothing about it. I have isolted the procedure with threads. But with this bad way, the user can't understand what goes wrong

Below, my code:

```
public static boolean access(String db, String ip, String usr, String pwd){
Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<>();

persistenceMap.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.database", db);
persistenceMap.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.host", ip);
persistenceMap.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.username", usr);
persistenceMap.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.password", pwd);

Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
Thread logThread = new Thread(() -> {
    Connection.EMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ogm-jpa-mongo", persistenceMap);
    Connection.EM = Connection.EMF.createEntityManager();
    Connection.isOpen = true;
});
Thread timeOut = new Thread( () -> {
    try{ Thread.sleep( 5000 ); }
    catch(InterruptedException ex){ }
    mainThread.interrupt();
});


logThread.start();
timeOut.start();

try{ logThread.join(); }
catch(InterruptedException ex){ return false; }

Connection.TM = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();

return Connection.isOpen;
```

}

The problem is that when I insert worng parameters, it is thrown a MongoSecurityException. But i can't catch it, I can only read it on the monitor-thread. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a result of the way your version of Hibernate catches the `MongoSecurityException`.  I believe the `MongoSecurityException` is caught inside a nested try catch block.

The correct answer here is to update your Hibernate version to the latest release.  However, if you would like to see that exception I think you can do the following.

```
String message = "";
try { 
   logThread.join(); 
} catch(Throwable e) { 
   throw e;
} catch(Exception e) {
   message = e.getMessage();
}
```

If that doesn't work you might be able to chain as follows.

```
String message = "";
try { 
   logThread.join(); 
} catch(Throwable e) { 
   e.getCause();
   e.getCause().getCause();
   e.getCause()..getCause().getCause();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the logThread doesn't stop if parameters are wrong. That's why I created timeOut thread!